# Ldap Authentication for Windows Standalone Servers Using Novell eDirectory

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication, gina

I have an LDAP server Novell eDirectory in my Environment through which has the user data. In my Environment i have set of Windows and Linux servers. I need to use this LDAP As the Authentication Source for for both the servers.

For Linux i need to achieve this by setting the linux as LDAP Client & extended edirectory schema for linux users and users are able to login into the machine and even able to create the home directories for the user. But the problem comes with the windows machines.

For windows machines i have used novell gina which authenticates the user using LDAP but it also requires a local or domain user credentials to login into the local system.Then for every user i have to create a local user on every system which is off target of purpose.

Then i have used pgina (Another Open Source Gina) through which i can authenticate the user using LDAP and it creates a profile for the user. Fine but it is also creating a local user with the LDAP username.If any admin changes password on the local machine for this user then the password of both the LDAP and local user will not be in sync.

How can i get the login behavoiur of active directory where it will authenticate against active directory (Think AD as LDAP) and creates a profile for you in the local system but never creates a local user.Anybody can throw some light on this to solve the issue?

Thanks and Regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using Open Enterprise server. If you are on OES linux, probably you can use [Domain Services for Windows](http://www.novell.com/products/openenterpriseserver/domain_services.html) This can help achieve what you want. You will not even need a gina login. Its a Domain emulator. So, there wont be any ldap login. It would be a kerberos login. Your eDirectory (and other related services) work exactly like AD domain. But nothing stops you to use the plain ldap login against eDirectory. You can continue to use the linux login as its now. If you are using gdm (gnome display manager) on linux it can do a domain login like the windows.

Comment: I dont have any active directory in my environment i have to use edirectory only then can this scenario be solved using domain services for windows only using edirectory

Comment: yes, it can.You dont need to have any active directory in your enviroment, it creates one. It convert your eDirectory to AD like.

Comment: try to solve by finding some simple solution if you can just live with that. Adopting dsfw will be a major change in your environment.

Comment: Thanks For your Suggestion i think this solution seems promising will try to build this solution........

Comment: what do you mean doesn't support Win 2k8 servers? adding win2k8 as a member server or cross forest trust between dsfw and win2k8? Both the thing will work fine.